# How to get the hours worked as integer or numeric in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I want to get the total of hours worked by employee per week. This is the code that I am using right now:

```
SELECT 
  Employee_Number
  ,CAST([DateTime] as Date) as 'DateTime'
  ,MIN([DateTime]) as 'MIN'
  ,MAX([DateTime]) as 'MAX'
  ,CONVERT(nvarchar, MAX([DateTime]) - MIN([DateTime]), 108) AS [Hours Worked]
FROM tblExtract 
GROUP BY
  Employee_Number, Cast([DateTime] as Date)
```

As you can see, it will be hard for me to get the total sum of the hours worked per employee at the end of the week because of the data type - nvarchar. I want to transfer the result into the rdlc using C#.

I have two questions:  1) Is there any way for me to get the total sum? 2) Should I convert it to integer or numeric?

Answer (score 0):

The correct method for this is the SQL [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms189794.aspx) function, with an appropriate first parameter.

To get a fractional number of hours worked, calculate the difference between `MIN` and `MAX` and divide by the appropriate scale.  Bear in mind that it will return an integer value, truncating any floating point amount.  Use either minutes or seconds to get fractional hours worked.

Here it is with 1 minute grain:

```
SELECT
    Employee_Number,
    CAST([DateTime] AS DATE) AS [DateTime],
    MIN([DateTime]) AS [Min],
    MAX([DateTime]) AS [Max],
    DATEDIFF(n, MIN([DateTime]), MAX([DateTime])) / 60.0 AS [Hours Worked]
FROM tblExtract
GROUP BY
    Employee_Number, CAST([DateTime] AS Date)
```

For accuracy down to the seconds level replace `n` with `ss` and divide by `3600.0`.